# Jquery UI DatePicker In a JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am trying to use a datepicker when editing a cell in a JQGrid. When I click in the cell it does change to a text box and the datepicker does display, but after selecting a date I get the following error thrown

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Missing instance data for this datepicker
```

Here is the code for the JQGrid

```
    var saverow = 0;

var savecol = 0;
$("#requestTable").jqGrid({
    url: url,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    altRows: 'true',
    colNames: ['id', 'Request Date', 'Name', 'HomePhone', 'Address', 'Contact Date(edit)', 'Email'],

    colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true },
                { name: 'RequestDate', index: 'RequestDate', width: 100 },
                { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', width: 125, sortable: false },
                { name: 'HomePhone', index: 'CabinetColor', width: 90, sortable: false },
                { name: 'FullAddressString', index: 'ShellColor', width: 260, sortable: false },
                { name: 'DealerContactDate', index: 'DealerContactDate', width: 105, editable: true,
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).blur(function () {
                                $("#requestTable").jqGrid("saveCell", saverow, savecol);
                                $("#requestTable").jqGrid("restoreCell", saverow, savecol);
                                $("#requestTable").trigger("reloadGrid");
                            });
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                                    $("#requestTable").jqGrid("saveCell", saverow, savecol);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }

                },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 110, sortable: false }

            ],
    cellEdit: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 50,
    rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "100%",
    cellurl: cellurl,
    afterEditCell: function (id, name, val, IRow, ICol) {
        saverow = IRow;
        savecol = ICol;
    }

});
```

Any thoughts why I am getting this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your textbox "**id**"?. It should contains any **space** or any **unsupported characters** may cause issue **jquery selector**, hence it throws the reported exceptions in date selection.